# Как преобразовать строчное значение в список?

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, list, python-faq

Есть строка: `"[1, 2, 3, 4]"`
Как эту строку можно преобразовать в список?

Comment: а как вы получаете такую строку?

Comment: @S.Nick получаю из базы данных. Ее версия не поддерживает хранение массивов, поэтому я храню их как строки

Comment: `Ее версия не поддерживает хранение массивов` почему бы не использовать *BLOB*? Например, вам нужно сохранить массив из 10 чисел типа `int` - вы преобразовываете его в массив байт, потом записываете в бд. И при получении проделываете тоже самое, только в обратном порядке. Посмотрите в сторону [struct](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) или обычных битовых операций.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Вариант 1

```
from ast import literal_eval

expr_str = "[1, 2, 3, 4]"

res = literal_eval(expr_str)
```

#### Вариант 2

```
import json

res = json.loads(expr_str)
```

#### Вариант 3

```
import yaml

res = yaml.safe_load(expr_str)
```

PS `yaml` умеет парсить не вполне валидные JSON строки, например JSON строки с одинарными кавычками вместо двойных (по стандарту).

### NOTE: [не используйте `eval()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice)

---

результат:

```
In [204]: res
Out[204]: [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 4):

Решение "в лоб", как иногда тут пишут ;) :

```
s = "[1, 2, 3, 4]"

arr = [int(i) for i in s.replace(']', '').replace('[', '').split(',')]

>>> arr
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: `s[1:-1].split(", ")` ?

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME да, это я погорячился с ```.replace()``` :)

Comment: почему не `s[1::3]`? ))

Comment: @TigerTV.ru а если среди чисел дву- и более значные?..

Comment: @Jack_oS, я знаю, но в условии ничего не указано про другие строки.) И решение OPOPTIMUSPRIME будет неверным к примеру если пробелы будут в начале строки.

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME, да, проверил, пробел можно убрать в split

Answer (score 3):

Еще 2 варианта, использующие регулярки:

1. через замену скобок:

```py
import re

a = " [1,   332,    35,4]   "
a = [int(i) for i in re.sub('[\[\]]', '', a).split(',')]
print(a)
```

2. поиск только чисел:

```py
import re

b = " [1,   332,    35,4]   "
b = [int(i) for i in re.findall('\d+', b)]
print(b)
```