# Преобразование строк датафрейма

Tags: python, pandas, анализ-данных

Из Яндекс.Метрика получаю DF (здесь сокращенная часть таблицы):

| Дата | Номер заказа | Источник |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-06-02 | ['6857886514054418'] | cityads |
| 2023-06-03 | ['6858636614093599','6858634464093342'] | cityads |
| 2023-06-03 | ['6858887364118002'] | 2gis |
| 2023-06-04 | ['6858025994065429'] | yandex |
| 2023-06-05 | ['6858706704101675','6858722124103264','6858887364118056'] | yandex |

Пытаюсь в поле "Номер заказа" убрать скобки с апострофами и запятыми и перенести значения, указанные через запятую, на новую строку с сохранением соответствующих дат и источников. Чтобы стало так:

| Дата | Номер заказа | Источник |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-06-02 | 6857886514054418 | cityads |
| 2023-06-03 | 6858636614093599 | cityads |
| 2023-06-03 | 6858634464093342 | cityads |
| 2023-06-03 | 6858887364118002 | 2gis |
| 2023-06-04 | 6858025994065429 | yandex |
| 2023-06-05 | 6858706704101675 | yandex |
| 2023-06-05 | 6858722124103264 | yandex |
| 2023-06-05 | 6858887364118056 | yandex |

Единственное, что получается, так это удалить скобки, используя код:

```
data['Номер заказа']=data['Номер заказа'].str.strip('[]')
```

Однако в ячейках остаются также по несколько значений, выделенных апострофами и разделенных запятыми.

Как начинающий специалист по Python прошу Сообщество помочь мне реализовать задуманную задачу.

Comment: А это строки или это списки строк? Если списки, то попробуйте сразу `data.explode('Номер заказа')`, возможно вам ничего и не нужно делать со строками

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```python
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_clipboard()
df.iloc[:, 1] = df.iloc[:, 1].str.replace("\[|\]|'", '', regex=True)
df.iloc[:, 1] = df.iloc[:, 1].str.split(',').tolist()
df = df.explode('Номер заказа')
print(df)
```

###### Вывод:

```
         Дата      Номер заказа Источник
0  2023-06-02  6857886514054418  cityads
1  2023-06-03  6858636614093599  cityads
1  2023-06-03  6858634464093342  cityads
2  2023-06-03  6858887364118002     2gis
3  2023-06-04  6858025994065429   yandex
4  2023-06-05  6858706704101675   yandex
4  2023-06-05  6858722124103264   yandex
4  2023-06-05  6858887364118056   yandex
```

Comment: Есть волшебная функция ast.literal_eval: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1243893/1365

Comment: @insolor да, согласен. Но за eval частенько втык дают, т.к. не безопасна.

Comment: Так это и не eval, это отдельная безопасная функция для парсинга литералов.

Comment: @insolor принял, спасибо :)

Comment: @insolor увидел ответ strawdog, как-то писал ответ про `eval`, более безопасный `ast.literal_eval`, и всё равно от Володарского втык получал. Anyway, парсинг не сильно усложняет код :)

Comment: Не знаю что за ситуация была, но eval или exec примерно никогда не нужно использовать (даже если сильно хочется), а ast.literal_eval - без проблем (кроме парсинга json, для этого есть свои инструменты). В целом, любой участник может ошибиться или не знать каких-то вещей.

Comment: @insolor да, скорее всего про `json` вопрос был, поэтому избегаю любой `eval`, если это возможно. К тому же в специфику библиотеки **ast** не погружался.

Comment: @DiMithras благодарю за ответ! Однако у меня возникает ошибка после Вашего кода: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'read_clipboard'. Можете помочь, с чем может быть связано?

Comment: @Никита необходимо выделить изначальную таблицу из вопроса, чтобы `pd.read_clipboard()` заработало. Это всё для того, чтобы повторить dataframe из вопроса. В вашем случае достаточно обращаться к `data`, как написали в комментарии к вопросу, и начинать с строки после clipboard, заменив `df` на `data`.

Comment: @DiMithras Понял! Спасибо Вам большое!

Answer (score 3):

```
from ast import literal_eval

df["Номер заказа"] = df["Номер заказа"].apply(literal_eval)
df = df.explode("Номер заказа")
```

Comment: Спасибо @strawdog !